# VuetifyJS: Access v-form disabled state in child components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

The Vuetify component `v-form` knows a `disabled` property, which is published down to child vuetify components like `v-text-field`, `v-input` etc. When the `disabled` property of the `v-form` is set to true, all child input fields are also (automatically) disabled.

But this only works for Vuetify `v-input`-like fields, but it seems that this does **not** work for own components. I want to be able to "inherit" the `disabled` prop
in a child component (to do my own disabled UI).

I don't want to pass the reactive data prop (formDisabled in my example), as this is too tedious: There would be a large nested bunch of components that all
explicitely would need the reactive data prop, which I don't want to implement: Obviously it IS working with Vuetify's own components, but how can I achieve
the same by myself?

An example:

```
<template>
    <v-form :disabled="formDisabled">
        <!-- 
            works, even WITHOUT explicitely binding formDisabled: 
            textfield gets en-/disabled according to the form state: 
        -->
        <v-text-field />

        <!-- does NOT work: Withoud bind the formDisabled prop, 
             I cannot get the form's disabled state in my own component: -->
        <MyOwnComponent />
    </v-form>
    <v-btn @click="formDisabled = !formDisabled">Toggle</v-btn>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            formDisabled: true
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

So how can I find out the form's disabled state, WITHOUT binding the `formDisabled` data prop explicitely to every own form child component?

Comment: Looks like Vuetify componets have the value injected from the v-form, so you could do the same in your component, I think it is `const {isDisabled} = inject('vuetify:form')`. Maybe it is also possible to import the injection function: `const {isDisabled} = useForm()` from composables/form.ts. 
Not sure if this is easier than just setting the prop though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, unfortunately 'vuetify:form' seems not to be a provided var from above, so it is not known as an injectable property. I guess there is no way around setting the prop ...

Comment: @AlexSchenkel As passing a props (disabled state) in each and every child component is not a good idea. You can achieve this by using `vuex` store or `pinia`.

Comment: I have create an answer with more details on how to inject the form. I think the best solution is to use [v-input](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/inputs/) though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [v-input](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/inputs/), it is the base for Vuetify inputs, you can use it to build Vuetify-like inputs which resolve disabled state (and all other validation) same as other Vuetify components.

If this does not work for you, you can manually resolve the disabled state similar to what Vuetify/v-input does, where the disabled state is propagated from form to inputs through injection.

In **Vuetify 3**, I can inject the form like this (using composition API):

```js
const form = inject(Symbol.for("vuetify:form"))
```

or like this:

```js
import {useForm} from 'vuetify/lib/composables/form'
const form = useForm()
```

which gives me an object of this interface:

```js
interface FormProvide {
  register: (item: {
    id: number | string
    validate: () => Promise<string[]>
    reset: () => void
    resetValidation: () => void
  }) => void
  unregister: (id: number | string) => void
  update: (id: number | string, isValid: boolean | null, errorMessages: string[]) => void
  items: Ref<FormField[]>
  isDisabled: ComputedRef<boolean>
  isReadonly: ComputedRef<boolean>
  isValidating: Ref<boolean>
  validateOn: Ref<FormProps['validateOn']>
}
```

And then in your component (from `vuetify/lib/composables/validation`):

```js
  const isDisabled = computed(() => !!(props.disabled || form != null && form.isDisabled.value));
```

In **Vuetify for Vue 2**, the whole form object is provided as "form", so this should work (I don't have a vue2 project to test it):

```js
export default {
  inject: ['form'],
  created() {
    console.log(this.form)
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! That was exactly what I was looking for. Such important concepts are just completely missing from the Vuetify doc, so I appreciate your help.

Even better: you can even watch on the `form.disabled` property in the child component

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for this problem statement is to use global `mixin`, which will be  applied to every Vue instance without explicitly passing as a prop for each and every child component.

As `formDisabled` is a read only property for each child, Here is the live demo **:**

*Note : Just for a demo purpose, I am demoing it in a pure Vue format, but you can modify it as per vuetify components and test.*

```js
// This is a global mixin, it is applied to every vue instance. 
// Mixins must be instantiated *before* your call to new Vue(...)
Vue.mixin({
  data: function() {
    return {
      get formDisabled() {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<input type="text" :disabled="formDisabled"/>'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form :disabled="formDisabled">
    <child></child>
  </form>
</div>
```